# Recyclerview and viewpager combined effect(Picture Galllery view)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am currently working on a project that simulate the same effect as the picture gallery where you have pictures listed in gridlayout and on click the image enlarges with other details as seen in the video below.
[Gallery effect sample](https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-aaf5fb0a1d.gif)

How can I make a swift change between recyclerview and viewpager2 to make this happen or any other ways to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this and the repository link is below.

https://github.com/darothub/balloonstorefront/tree/ft-switch-recyclerview-viewpager

Feel free to drop any suggestion